# Kendo ToolTip in Kendo Grid to show a page By URL

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tooltip

I have a grid with first column having a template for

```
   columns:
        [
            {
                field: "KedocTitle", template: "<a href='#=FileRef#'
```

So #=FileRef# brings the URL correctly and users can go to that page.
Now I have a requirement to show that page in a big tooltip.
So I added this:

```
  ChronGrid.table.kendoTooltip({    
        filter: "td:nth-child(1)", //this filter selects the first column
        position: "right",
        width: 900,
        height: 700,
        content: { url: "#=FileRef#"
        }
    }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

The result is the same page showing in the tooltip, not the URL that #=FileRef# has.

Any Idea How to do that?

Comment: You're needing to actually render the page in the tooltip or just show a preview image of the page in the tooltip?

Comment: Render the page which is a pdf file

Answer (score 0):

The `content: { url: "#=FileRef#" }` expression in this case is not evaluated dynamically in the context of the Grid cell template, that's why `"#=FileRef#"` is treated as the same page URL.

You have three options:

1. Initialize a separate Tooltip instance for each table cell in the `dataBound` event of the Grid.
2. Initialize one Tooltip instance and use a **function** for the [`content` setting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip#configuration-content) of the ToolTip. The function should return a string with the content.
3. Use [`requestStart`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip#events-requestStart) and Ajax, similar to the [Loading content with AJAX](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/ajax)

Comment: Spoken too soon :-) Works fine with all browsers but IE 10 when the URL points to a pdf file in the same DNS name as the calling page. when the URL is outside, (like Bing) it shows fine.  :-) Any idea why?